# Slight metallic ringing noise when clutch pedal is our, goes away when clutch is depressed

Tags: noise, troubleshooting, clutch, manual-transmission, mini-cooper

I have a 2013 Mini Cooper non-S (R56) with manual transmission. I’m hearing a new noise, and I’m trying to diagnose what it is. The noise is faint but noticeable, but hard to get on video. It’s a faint metallic ringing noise, almost like if you had tinnitus.

This noise is present when the clutch is not depressed. I can hear it when standing and when driving. In both cases, when I press the clutch in, it goes away immediately.

I have hear/seen videos of clutch bearing noises, but in those instances it’s the opposite of what I’m encountering. In those videos the noise only happens when the clutch is pressed in. I have the opposite problem.

Does anyone have any idea of what it could be or further trouble shooting suggestions?

P.S. no issues are actually felt when driving, it’s just this audible ringing noise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!